# What are the defaults for a task queue in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

Suppose I create a new queue in my `queue.yaml` file as:

```
queue:
- name: my_queue
```

What would be the equivalent queue with all parameters specified?

Here's what I could gather from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Python_Configuring_retry_attempts_for_failed_tasks) so far.

```
queue:
- name: my_queue
  mode: push
  bucket_size: 5
  target: <the same version that enqueued the task>
  rate: ???
  max_concurrent_requests: ???
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: ???
    task_age_limit: ???
    min_backoff_seconds: ???
    max_backoff_seconds: ???
    max_doublings: ???
```

Can you help me fill in the gaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best stab at this is

```
queue:
- name: my_queue
  mode: push
  bucket_size: 5
  target: <the same version that enqueued the task>
  rate: 5
  max_concurrent_requests: ∞
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: ∞
    task_age_limit: ∞
    min_backoff_seconds: 0.1
    max_backoff_seconds: 3600.0
    max_doublings: 16
```

The rate is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#Python_The_default_queue).

The rest of the numbers I got from taskqueue_service_pb.py, which you will find in the python SDK, where there is a class called `TaskQueueRetryParameters`, which looks like this:

```
class TaskQueueRetryParameters(ProtocolBuffer.ProtocolMessage):
  has_retry_limit_ = 0
  retry_limit_ = 0
  has_age_limit_sec_ = 0
  age_limit_sec_ = 0
  has_min_backoff_sec_ = 0
  min_backoff_sec_ = 0.1
  has_max_backoff_sec_ = 0
  max_backoff_sec_ = 3600.0
  has_max_doublings_ = 0
  max_doublings_ = 16
```

`task_retry_limit` and `task_age_limit` are set to 0 - in other words, there is no limit. Same for `max_concurrent_requests`, which is defined in another class called `TaskQueueUpdateQueueRequest`.

Comment: Thanks... it's incredible that they don't have these things documented anywhere.