# App Engine: What are the Default Retry Parameters for Failed Taskqueues

Tags: google-app-engine, default, task-queue

Google App Engine has a robust set parameters to automatically retry failed tasks in the distributed tasksqueue. While the [documentation explains what these parameters do](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue?hl=en#retry_parameters), it fails to specify what the default parameters are.

What are the defaults for the Taskqueue's retry parameters. More specifically, what are the default values for the following retry parameters:

- `task_retry_limit`
- `task_age_limit`
- `min_backoff_seconds`
- `max_backoff_seconds`
- `max_doublings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour is described at the beginning of [this section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue?hl=en#Python_Configuring_retry_attempts_for_failed_tasks):

> Tasks executing in the task queue can fail for many reasons. If a task
>   fails to execute (by returning any HTTP status code outside of the
>   range 200–299), App Engine retries the task until it succeeds. By
>   default, the system gradually reduces the retry rate to avoid flooding
>   your application with too many requests, but schedules retry attempts
>   to recur at a maximum of once per hour until the task succeeds.

From this description and by observing the logs for an actually failing task in a push queue with no retry config (thus using defaults for all these parameters) I "derived" these values:

- task_retry_limit: None
- task_age_limit: None
- min_backoff_seconds: 0.1
- max_backoff_seconds: 3600
- max_doublings: None

These would be some of the logs I looked at on my development server - I didn't wait for the retry interval to settle down, tho:

```
INFO     2015-09-02 12:50:54,670 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:50:54,670 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.100 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:50:54,774 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:50:54,774 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.200 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:50:54,983 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:50:54,983 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.400 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:50:55,394 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:50:55,394 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.800 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:50:56,206 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:50:56,206 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 1.600 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:50:57,815 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:50:57,815 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 3.200 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:51:01,058 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:51:01,058 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 6.400 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:51:07,507 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:51:07,507 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 12.800 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:51:20,346 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:51:20,346 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 25.600 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:51:45,988 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:51:45,989 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 51.200 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:52:37,224 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:52:37,225 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 102.400 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:54:19,668 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:54:19,668 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 204.800 seconds
INFO     2015-09-02 12:57:44,508 module.py:808] my_module: "POST /my/task_q/path HTTP/1.1" 403 55
WARNING  2015-09-02 12:57:44,509 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 409.600 seconds
```

Edit: Actually I found an even better answer which I used to correct mine (I previously missed the 0.100s log entries burried between others): [What are the defaults for a task queue in AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306301/what-are-the-defaults-for-a-task-queue-in-appengine)